# Regex works for non digits, why it doesn't for digits?

Tags: ruby, regex

You can test it here: http://rubular.com/r/8tNjR6dVRu

Test String:

```
                                                                                   Folha: 1 /2
                                      História Escola

 Nome:              MARCOS MARCO MARCA                                                     1111111

 Data Nascimento:   7 de agosto de 2000
```

Result for

```
(?<=Nome:)(\D*)
```

MARCOS MARCO MARCA

( with spaces. Is there a easy way to remove it? )

Now, I wanted to get the numbers, I tried the logical

```
(?<=Nome:)(\d*)
```

But it doesn't work.

Can someone explain me why?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to match? there are no digits following `Nome`

Comment: So you want to match the numbers on the same line as `Nome:` and discard all the whitespace and `marcos marco marca` text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to MATCH the non-digits, but CAPTURE the digits:

```
(?<=Nome:)\D*(\d+)
```

This starts after the `Nome:` and ignores everything non-digit. Then it captures the digits.

[Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/3rgqXnYg2M)

Comment: Thank you, thats what I wanted. I didn't understand why it doesn't work for (?<=Nome:).*(\d+).